# Merging httpClient Observables in one dynamically depending on page count

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have API which gives data partialy (by pages). I get page count on first request.

On client I need to concat pages in one Observable. Trying something like this:

```
all$: Observable<Service[]>;
iterator$ = new BehaviorSubject(1);

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  this.all$ = this.iterator$.pipe(
    concatMap(page => http.get<Service[]>('/service', {params: {page: page.toString()}}).pipe(
      tap(() => (ifNotLastPage) ? this.iterator$.next(++page) : null),
    )),
  );
}
```

and get only last page

Comment: It looks like you're looking for [`expand`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-expand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly I got:

```
all$: Observable<Service[]>;

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  this.all$ = this.getData().pipe(
    expand(result => {
      const next = getNextPageNumber(result);

      return (next) ? this.getData(next) : empty();
    }),
    map(result => result.body),
    concatMap(typeCasting(Service)),
    toArray<Service>(),
  );

}

getData(page = 1): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
  return this.http.get<Config>('/service', { observe: 'response', params: { page: page.toString() } });
}
```

Thanx to [@martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310726/martin) 
and this article [RxJS: Understanding Expand](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-expand-a5f8b41a3602)